# How to make UITextField and Round Rect Button transparent?

Tags: iphone, uitextfield

I have a view with a button and three UITextFields. The view's background is an image. I want UITextField's and Round Rect Button's backgrounds to be transparent, so the have their functions and display text, but there are no backgrounds. Adding a transparent image as a background doesn't help.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pheelicks said for `UIButton` can create it with type `UIButtonTypeCustom`.

For `UITextField` set its border style to `UITextBorderStyleNone`.

Comment: Hmm.. Another problem appeared. Is it possible to make a border around the button?

Comment: See this question about adding border to UILabel: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2311591/how-to-draw-border-around-a-uilabel I believe that approach should work for all UIView subclasses

Comment: Yep, it worked for the button, but it's rectangle. Any way to make it the same shape as default button?

Answer (score 1):

For the button you need to change the button type to:

```
button.buttonType = UIButtonTypeCustom;
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/915416/is-there-an-way-to-make-an-invisible-uibutton-that-will-still-be-there-and-catc)

As for the textfields, I don't think you can make them transparent. One solution would be to set the background image of each textfields to the image that would be showing through if the textfields were transparent. If you get it pixel perfect then it'll look as if the textfields are transparent

Answer (score 1):

`[[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom]                                      initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];`