# UIButton with cust. background looks bad when pressed

Tags: ios, interface-builder, uibutton

I have a UIButton with a custom background that I set in the Interface Builder (see picture). It looks nice, but in the pressed state it gets really ugly (see the 2nd picture). What's going on here?

Normal:

[image: see picture]

Pressed:

[image]

Comment: It honestly doesn't look that bad

Comment: I'd recommend setting the background images for the button in the normal state and a different one for touch down, say with a highlighted inner edge for example.

Comment: What about perhaps changing what it does in the highlighted state? I recall there is a section in the right column of the Ib when you select a button to choose what it does, along with other attributes in the highlighted state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[btn setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"button_red.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(12, 12, 20, 12)] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btn setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"button_red_pressed.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(12, 12, 20, 12)] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

This should solve the problem.

Also, change your button style to Custom, this will remove that blue button background.

Comment: Yes, looks like it'd do the trick. Interesting though that in the similar older discussions people just seem to use one image, not two. I thought iOS would be able to animate the press without an extra image...

Comment: iOS can do as you suggest... see the addition to my answer

Comment: If you use Custom, you will get only your stuff, not the iOS blue button.

Comment: I changed it to custom, but the ugliness is still there, without the blue peeking through.

Comment: I ended up creating my own "pressed" image (normal and @2x), and doing something similar to your answer:    

UIImage *btnNameImageNormal = [UIImage imageNamed:@"button_red.png"];
[self.deleteButton setBackgroundImage:btnNameImageNormal forState:UIControlStateNormal];
UIImage *btnNameImagePressed = [UIImage imageNamed:@"button_red_dark.png"];
[self.deleteButton setBackgroundImage:btnNameImagePressed forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

Answer (score 0):

Post some code or maybe the image itself. It looks as if you might need to declare your 'pressed' image with one of [`UIImage`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006890)'s `resizableImage*` methods. It's stretching to fill the button rect.

Also, I'm fond of the `MOButton` and `MOGlassButton` classes used in the [iPhone SOCKS project](http://code.google.com/p/iphone-socks-proxy/) (handy in itself).

Update

The following worked for me, it even animated it dark when pressed:

[image]

Comment: This is the image: http://i.stack.imgur.com/2jkRR.png. There isn't any code for this, it's all done in the Interface Builder. I've tried doing it in code as described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/915416/is-there-an-way-to-make-an-invisible-uibutton-that-will-still-be-there-and-cat, but got the same result: looks good in normal state, bad in pressed state.

Comment: You've set the image property, not the background. This way, your button can't have any text.

Comment: So... does it look OK on a device when pressed?

Comment: It might be something you missed in the setup. Did you copy a previously-existing button? I set mine up from scratch. Anyway, glad you found a solution!